# Fopen file with dir name in Mint with C

Tags: c, fopen

I am using

```
FILE *fp = fopen("pasta/test.txt",w);
```

but this line doesn´t create a file in folder "pasta", i am creating a file with name "pasta/test.txt", can you help me?

Comment: First thing first: You can't use e.g. `fopen` to create directories, for that you have to use e.g. the [`mkdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) system call. Secondly, when posting code, please post ***working*** code. See e.g. [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Did you check the reason for failure? `errno`?

Comment: what command can i use to create a directories and a file ?

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16153477/how-to-create-a-file-in-a-specific-directory it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10147990/1430607) (it is not a duplicate) the distribution you are using is irrelevant, since those are POSIX calls. Google them,  is good to know them

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return value of `fopen` and use `errno`.  The `perror` function is quite useful:

```
FILE *fp = fopen("/pasta/test.txt", "w");
if (fp == NULL) {
   perror("Opening file failed:");
}
```